# Drupal error - Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET

Tags: drupal

Installed Drupal 10/ MariaDB with Docker. Managed through the installation wizard, but when I go to the homepage after installation completes I see: (had to enable debugging)

```
The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.

Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET http://localhost:8083/" in Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest() (line 128 of /opt/drupal/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php).
Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->matchRequest(Object) (Line: 106)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\EventListener\RouterListener->onKernelRequest(Object, 'kernel.request', Object)
call_user_func(Array, Object, 'kernel.request', Object) (Line: 111)
Drupal\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch(Object, 'kernel.request') (Line: 139)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object, 1) (Line: 74)
Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 58)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\Session->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\KernelPreHandle->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 48)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\ReverseProxyMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\NegotiationMiddleware->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 51)
Drupal\Core\StackMiddleware\StackedHttpKernel->handle(Object, 1, 1) (Line: 681)
Drupal\Core\DrupalKernel->handle(Object) (Line: 19)
```

Here's my docker-compose file:

```
version: '3'
services:
    drupal:
        image: drupal:10.0.2
        ports:
          - 8083:80
        volumes:
          - ./drupal_modules:/var/www/html/modules
          - ./drupal_profiles:/var/www/html/profiles
          - ./drupal_themes:/var/www/html/themes
          - ./drupal_sites:/var/www/html/sites
        # restart: always
    mariadb:
        image: mariadb:10.10
        volumes:
            - mariadb:/var/lib/mysql
        environment:
            TZ: "Europe/Rome"
            MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: "no"
            MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "rootpwd"
            MYSQL_USER: 'drupal'
            MYSQL_PASSWORD: 'drupal'
            MYSQL_DATABASE: 'drupal'
volumes:
    mariadb:
    # drupal_modules:
    # drupal_profiles:
    # drupal_themes:
    # drupal_sites:
```

I can successfully view database and table in the mariadb container:

```
> docker exec -it 348cd7dc8853 sh
# mysql -udrupal -p           
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MariaDB monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MariaDB connection id is 4
Server version: 10.10.2-MariaDB-1:10.10.2+maria~ubu2204 mariadb.org binary distribution

Copyright (c) 2000, 2018, Oracle, MariaDB Corporation Ab and others.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

MariaDB [(none)]> show databases
    -> ;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| drupal             |
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
2 rows in set (0.000 sec)

MariaDB [(none)]> use drupal
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed
MariaDB [drupal]> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_drupal |
+------------------+
| batch            |
| cache_config     |
| cache_container  |
| cache_data       |
| cachetags        |
| config           |
| key_value        |
| queue            |
| sequences        |
| sessions         |
| user__roles      |
| users            |
| users_data       |
| users_field_data |
+------------------+
14 rows in set (0.001 sec)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run into this issue before as well. While I have yet to find the cause of the issue, the solution is to run a drush cache clear: `drush cache-rebuild`